# Differentiate between different constraint violations in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I have a database table which has both Foreign key and Unique key constraints. To make changes in the database table, i am using java application which uses hibernate. To be more precise i am doing `Session.save()` to make changes in database table. My code looks like this.

```
try{
    transaction.begin();
    ------logic-------
    session.save();
    transaction.commit();
}catch(ConstarintViolationException exception){
    ---here is problem------
}
```

In case of any type constraint violation hibernate throws the same exception named `ConstraintViolationException`.

My question is what should i do to identify that what constraint has caused the exception. I tried doing

```
exception.getConstraintName()
```

But unfortunately i am getting `null` as output.

I want to differentiate between the two cases because i want to translate the hibernate exception to my own exception before sending it to client.

Answer (score 0):

I would say let the database detect the violations of the constraint.....

Or

You can have something like the below class which might help in your case to catch the constraint violation exceptions...

```
public class DataIntegrityViolationExceptionsAdvice {
    public void afterThrowing(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) throws DataIntegrityViolationException {
        // extract the affected database constraint name:
        String constraintName = null;
        if ((ex.getCause() != null) && (ex.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
            constraintName = ((ConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause()).getConstraintName();
        }
        // create a detailed message from the constraint name if possible
        String message = ConstraintMsgKeyMappingResolver.map(constraintName);
        if (message != null) {
            throw new DetailedConstraintViolationException(message, ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i am getting "null" as output from getConstraintName() method :-( :-(